# Array not an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, var-dump

Very simple and probably noob question about php. i run the following;

```
var_dump($this->criteria);
```

which returns me :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[24]
public 'id' => string '3C222489-4BE4-47BB-A731-EFCF98B9979F' (length=36)
public 'parentId' => string '_001' (length=4)
public 'template' => string '_100' (length=4)
public 'name' => string 'New Report' (length=10)
public 'description' => 
object(SimpleXMLElement)[23]
public 'breakdown' => string 'talkgroup' (length=9)
public 'selectedColumns' => 
array
  0 => string 'talkgroup' (length=9)
  1 => string 'id' (length=2)  
public 'dc' => string '1337185046621' (length=13)
```

Great! so now I can see that selectedColums is an array.. so

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did you press "Ask Question" before you finished typing? I hope so, for your sake...

Comment: ... connection reset by peer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your question is:

> How can I determine whether `selectedColums` is an array?

Try this:

```
is_array($this->criteria->description->selectedColumns)
```

Comment: Don't know what happened. Sorry all, first post. however the answers correct, which is damn impressive!